# Finding the value with least characters in a Column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In the Column of df['Stem'] i want to find the word with least number of characters for each row and put that value in df['lab']

Current Output

```
group           stem                                      lab
-----------------  --------- ---------------------  -------------
notif           notify, notified                                nan
face-to-fac     face-to-face                                    nan
propo           proposed                                        nan
lift            lifted                                          nan
govern          governed, governing, government, governance     nan
constitut          constitute, constitutional                   nan
exp                expedient                                    nan
prev               preventing, prevent                          nan
tre                treat, treatment                             nan
work               working, works                               nan
```

Expected Output

```
group           stem                                      lab
-----------------  --------- ---------------------  -------------
notif           notify, notified                                notify
face-to-fac     face-to-face                                    face-to-face
propo           proposed                                        proposed
lift            lifted                                          lifted
govern          governed, governing, government, governance     governed
constitut       constitute, constitutional                      constitute
exp             expedient                                       expedient
prev            preventing, prevent                             prevent
tre             treat, treatment                                treat
work            working, works                                  works
```

Tried

```
df['lab'] = df.stem.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: min(x, key=len))
```

but its giving

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to obtain lists of strings from the strings in `stem` and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) the builtin `min` function setting `key=len` so that it returns the shortest string:

```
df['lab'] = df.stem.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: min(x, key=len))
```

---

Result for some of the rows:

```
        group                                            stem         lab
0       notif                                notify, notified      notify
1  ace-to-fac                                      ace-to-fac  ace-to-fac
2      govern     governed, governing, government, governance    governed
```

Comment: this is amazing :)

Comment: getting Error TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: Not sure what could be raising that... works fine with the shared sample. Is it pointing to a line in particular? @virus

Comment: @yatu Solved Did this in starting   ''' df1['stem'] = df1['stem'].astype(str) '''

Comment: Glad you got it to work @virus. Don't forget you can upvote/ accept. Thanks!

Comment: @virus you can accept by checking the unchecked tick right under the voting option